How to margin text in Textedit with Stylesheet on Qt
I have a project that uses PyQt5 to create a GUI. I used StyleSheet to change the widget appearance. Everything is fine but there is only 1 thing
It's not okay. It's about left and center margin of the text in the textbox. I tried looking on stackoverflow and the Qt forum but didn't see anyone who had a way to margin the text.
This is image my GUI:

This is my styleSheet:
QWidget{
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
border-top-right-radius:10px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
border-top-left-radius:10px;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

}
QSpinBox {
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
border-top-right-radius:10px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
border-top-left-radius:10px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
font: 75 10pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
}
QSpinBox::up-button {
width:20px;
     height:20px;
}
QSpinBox::down-button {
width:20px;
     height:20px;
}
QDoubleSpinBox {
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
border-top-right-radius:10px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
border-top-left-radius:10px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
font: 75 10pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
}
QDoubleSpinBox::up-button {
width:20px;
     height:20px;
}
QDoubleSpinBox::down-button {
width:20px;
     height:20px;
}
QTextEdit{
border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
border-top-right-radius:20px;
border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
border-top-left-radius:20px;
background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
QComboBox{
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
border-top-right-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border-top-left-radius:5px;
background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

How to align the text in Qt with styleSheet?
(I not good in english so i sorry if my question look weird)
Update: This is image my Textbox:


Which text do you want to align? Your QLabel (tên khách hàng, số điện thoại, etc.) ? You would like to align them on the left and not on the right?
Or is it the text in the button (xóa khách hàng, ...)? Or something else?

Have you try QTextEdit { margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 2px; } ?

Sorry but your question is unclear. What is the text you cannot align? Are you referring to the four QTextEdit selected in the second picture? If that's the case, then it seems that you want to use them as one line entry field, and using QTextEdit is wrong, since it's intended for formatted multi line text. Use QLineEdit, which provides the alignment property by default.

Also, unrelated but extremely important: 1. always use layout managers, never rely on fixed geometries; 2. avoid QWidget {} without specific selectors, otherwise it will be inherited by *all widgets and cause issues in complex ones: if you want to set properties for the central widget, then use the object name selector: in your case, it probably will be QWidget#centralwidget (but check the correct name in the object inspector, it's the top level widget of the main window).

Maybe you can try the following QSS
QTextEdit{padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px;
